# In django python i want to get the users name as well as only the active users in the dropdown

Tags: python, html, django, database

I am having two html forms where i fill the forms and submit and show the forms right now I want two fields to be worked simultaneously I have two fields

This is what I am fetching the value of database and showing in html form as dropdown

```
  <select name="assignee" required id="assignee" class="form-control">
       <option hidden value="">Select Assignee</option>
       {% for r in b %}
       <option>{{r.firstname}} {{r.lastname}}</option>
       {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

This is my status dropdown to select the assignees are active or inactive now from the above html snippet I want to do something that it only fetches the active users right now I am fetching the all users but I want to fetch only the active users and show it in the dropdown and not the inactive how can I do this if anyone knows please help.

```
<select required name="status" id="status" class="form-control">
   <option hidden value="">Select Status</option>
   <option value = "Active">Active</option>
   <option value="Inactive">Inactive</option>
</select>
```

Comment: so you want to get active users from db only?

Comment: yes only the active users who will fill the form

Answer (score 0):

Then in the view that renders the first snippet, you have

```
  b = Users.objects.all()
```

make it

```
  b = Users.objects.filter(is_active=True)
```